# Cassandra python driver execute_async with callback not working as expected

Tags: python, cassandra

I am trying to query data from Cassandra using the datastax python driver. I would like this query to be as fast as possible. I was using the synchronous `session.execute` method but would like to use the asynchronous `session.execute_async` as it will presumably be more efficient by not having to wait for the row processing code to complete.

When I try to use this approach, as per the documentation it does not work. I am on Ubuntu 14.0.4 using Cassandra 2.1.3 and the v2.5 cassandra python driver.

The following code is enough to reproduce the issue on my machine:

```
def print_row_count(rows, label):
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        do_something = row
    print "{}: processed {} rows".format(label, i+1)

def print_err(reason):
    print "Error: {}".format(reason)

cluster = Cluster(['192.168.1.100'])
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace("foo")
session.default_fetch_size = 200
future_res = session.execute_async("SELECT * FROM bar LIMIT 1000;")
future_res.add_callback(print_row_count, 'Async')
future_res.add_errback(print_err)
```

When I execute this code nothing gets printed.

However when I add into the blocking call to `ResponseFuture.result` that synchronous call gets executed as well as the original async calls.

```
block_future_res = future_res.result()
print_row_count(block_future_res, 'BlockFuture')
```

Output after running with these two lines added:

```
Async: processed 200 rows
Async: processed 200 rows
Async: processed 200 rows
Async: processed 200 rows
Async: processed 200 rows
BlockFuture: processed 1000 rows
```

Perhaps I misunderstand how the callback system works but I can't see anywhere in the [docs](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.add_callback) where you need to call `result()` first for the callbacks to execute.

Any help appreciated.

Update:

The initial question about callback behaviour is answered by @WangST
However I wanted to be able to page through async_executions and the following code allows this:

```
future = session.execute_async("SELECT * FROM metadata LIMIT 1000;")
future.add_callback(print_row_count, 'Async')
future.add_errback(print_err)

# Call this once so that the future has_more_pages value is set
future_res = future.result()
while future.has_more_pages:
    future.start_fetching_next_page()
    future_res = future.result()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without:

```
block_future_res = future_res.result()
```

the main thread has nothing to do and exit, before the `execute_async()` query finish. so nothing printed.

Comment: Ok that makes sense that the main thread exits because those callbacks happen on another thread. Not sure why the `Async: processed 200 rows` code only gets executed once when you just have the line `block_future_res = future_res.result()` but gets executed 5 times when you include the next line: `print_row_count(block_future_res, 'BlockFuture')`. This is telling me I should just use a PagedResult or I am still missing how to use execute_async properly with multiple pages of results

Comment: What I am saying really is that I expected there would a away to page through results using execute_async or should I stick to execute and use to PagedResult class to handle paging? Thanks

Comment: The SQL statement ``LIMIT 1000`` limit the records to 1000. If you want multiple pages of results, maybe you can add another async SQL query as a future to the previous, like ``future_res.add_callback(session.execute_async("...")`` . The SQL query is in a chain, it will continue if success, or ``print_err`` will be executed.